# New CSP violation spontainiously happening in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, locker-service, csp

I have some code in a visualforce page that used a custom js library to build an excel file client side from an object generated on the server side and then force the browser to download the file.

This was working fine in both lightning and classic until about 10 days ago when it stopped working in lightning. Now the server generates the object but the page fails to download the file once it has created it.

Our code that calls the 3rd party library is below

```
var workBookOut = XLSX.write(workBook,
    {
        bookType:'xlsx',
        bookSST:true,
        type: 'binary'
    }
);
saveAs(
    new Blob([saveToArrayBuffer(workBookOut)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), excelName + '.xlsx'
);
```

A CSP directive is now being violated, which appears to be the error. I assume this is something to do with the new strict enforcement Salesforce is adding. However I was under the impression that Salesforce was not enforcing stricter CSP in production orgs for another release. I look on the org and the critical update is not active yet.

Reading the documentation I saw about adding a CSP trusted site but this is not a connect-src error so it doesn't seem to apply. I did test it out.

The error we get in the chrome console is below.

```
<namespace>.ap5.visual.force.com/:1 Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src https: mailto: *.ap5.visual.force.com".

(index):1 Not allowed to load local resource: blob:https://<namespace>.ap5.visual.force.com/f035dc0e-ae07-47be-8e4a-c8443e93657b
```

Has Salesforce changed something else recently that might be causing this issue?

Any other pointers on what is going wrong here and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks All!

Comment: Update on this one. We rebuilt the page to use a different salesforce only method that didn't rely on a third party lib. Also the issue disappeared on the latest version of chrome but still happened on other browsers and older versions of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers:

- Strict CSP is only enabled if you turn on the critical update.
- You can turn Strict CSP off.

If that doesn't solve it, ping us back: you should not get that behavior. Salesforce typically only makes such changes with lots of warnings and a clear date of enablement, usually with a new release. Here is the current information, subject to change as I will explain below:

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_stricter_csp.htm

At Trailhead DX, Salesforce hinted that the critical update will be converted  into a preference because many third party libraries are not ready for it. This change is scheduled for Winter '19 (subject to change).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can confirm that strict CSP is off in all the orgs where we are seeing this problem. One of the orgs that has this issue is a production org so as far as I can tell would never have had strict CSP turned on.

Comment: I believe I saw your session at TrailheadX. It would be awesome if strict CSP was optional as breaking 3rd party libraries would be a big problem.

Comment: As FYI this is the lib we are using. We are using version 1.1.20151003 https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/src/FileSaver.js

Comment: any update on this one? We are still getting this error.

Comment: Owen, could you add to your original post with an example on how you are using FileSaver? There are a few restrictions around Blob and I want to make sure we are looking at the right problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Much appreciated! I have added the code that calls fileSaver above. Let me know if that is what you needed. Happy to add as much detail as you need to help us out with this problem.

Comment: Hi @JF Paradis, sorry to keep bothering you about this one but do you have an update for us. This is really causing us issues with our app exchange product. If there is a different avenue that I should be following this up through can you please let me know. I have not yet gone to SF support as I imagine that would end up with you anyway. Cheers